# navbar-toggle displays different horizontal overflow view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I have this navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header ">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QuADS</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_collapse">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_collapse" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_collapse">
                       <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_collapse">
                       <a href="#">View Activity</a></li>
                    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_collapse">
                       <a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

In mobile view, if I click that icon-bar, it toggles to and fro perfectly. I wanted it to be toggled, even when I click on the menu items. So I added `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_collapse"`to menu list items too.

Now mobile view, works as I expected. But desktop view,displays some abnormal horizontal overflow when I click on menu items. see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc7xescn/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The only thing i can think of is creating 2 navbars 1 with `hidden-lg` and `hidden-md`

The other one with `hidden-sm` and`hidden-xs`

This way you can create different navabars for different views!

Edit2: If you give the navbar the classes: `hidden-lg` and `hidden-md` it means it will not show on large screens.

If you give the navbar the classes: `hidden-sm` and`hidden-xs` it means it will not show on small screens.

This way you can give the navbar you already have the `hidden-sm` and`hidden-xs` classes and you remove the`target="#navbar_collapse"`.

And you can create a second one with the classes `hidden-lg` and `hidden-md` for the mobile view.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If i remove `data-target="#navbar_collapse"` when I click on list items in mobile view, it does not toggle

Comment: What do you want to toggle when you click the list items on mobile view? For me there is no diffirence when i remove data-target="#navbar_collapse"

Comment: In mobile view, if I click icon-bar, it toggles back and forth. I want same behaviour even when I click on menu items

Comment: When I click on menu item, it should close menu item div

Comment: So, If i add `data-target="#navbar_collapse` to list items, toggling works though i click on list items. But prob occurs in display view

Comment: @Learning i changed my answer

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Learning Understand it now?